# Mapbox GL JS and Ionic 2 RC3 issue : mapbox-gl\js\util\util.js Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, ionic2, mapbox-gl-js

I have the following issue in my Web browser while trying to use ionic 2 and MapBox GL JS (I did a simple ionic serve) :

```
Error: Module parse failed: C:\Workspace\mapBox\node_modules\mapbox-gl\js\util\util.js Unexpected token (15:35)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * @private
|  */
| exports.easeCubicInOut = function(t: number): number {
|     if (t <= 0) return 0;
|     if (t >= 1) return 1;
    at eval (\C:\Workspace\mapBox\node_modules\mapbox-gl\js\util\util.js:1:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http:// localhost:8100/build/main.js:99:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http:// localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at eval (\C:\Workspace\mapBox\node_modules\mapbox-gl\js\ui\map.js:3:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http:// localhost:8100/build/main.js:5412:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http:// localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at eval (\C:\Workspace\mapBox\node_modules\mapbox-gl\js\mapbox-gl.js:11:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http:// localhost:8100/build/main.js:3644:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http:// localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at eval (\C:\Workspace\mapBox\src\pages\home\home.ts:2:68)
```

Those are the steps I followed :

I started a new ionic 2 blank project

//Installing app-scripts

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

//Installing mapbox plugin and typings

```
npm install --save-dev mapbox-gl
typings install --save --global dt~geojson
typings install --save --global dt~mapbox-gl
```

My code is quite simple, and I have no typescript issue

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib2xpdmllcnBvdW0iLCJhIjoiY2l3OGJ5eDl0MDAyaDJvcDV1bWhrdWRsYSJ9.FxIRs2au2Rd5OR1pQlZi8A';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9'
        });
    }
}
```

I don't see what type of file the error is referencing about.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'
```

And don't share your accessToken ;-)

Comment: That's a public access token, it's fine to share.